# Cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const Line' to 'Line &' explanation?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

This method:

```
bool Point::Intersects(const Line& line) const {
    return (line.ContainsPoint(*this, false));
}
```

causes this error: cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const Line' to 'Line &'
This change:

```
bool Point::Intersects(const Line& line) const {
    return const_cast<Line&>(line).ContainsPoint(*this, false);
}
```

fixes the error, but doesn't seem the right way to fix the issue. Why is the original method considered an error?

If it helps, `ContainsPoint(const Point& point, bool isInfinite)` is non-const and all methods it calls are non-const as well.

Comment: @iammilind: He has the prototype in his last paragraph.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You actually provided the answer yourself, in a sense.

In your `Intersects` method, the parameter `line` is declared `const`. This restricts how you can use this variable. Specifically, you can only call `const` methods on it, and you can only pass it to methods expecting a `const` Line object.

However, you pointed out that `ContainsPoint` is not declared `const`. So it does not satisfy the requirement mention above (i.e. calling a non-`const` method on a `const` object is not allowed). This is why the original method generates the error, and it also explains why your second version works, since the restriction is alleviated via the `const_cast`.

The real problem is in the declaration of `ContainsPoint` (and probably also with whatever methods it calls, as they are also non-`const`). There appears to be a large design flaw here. Since the purpose of `ContainsPoint` is to check whether or not a `Point` is on a `Line`, side-effects will be unexpected. So there should be no reason for it to not be a `const` method. In fact (and your example shows this), users of `Line` would *expect* `ContainsPoint` to be a `const` method. Therefore, the real solution is to change the design of the `Line` class so that methods like `ContainsPoint` are declared `const`, and only methods which clearly change the state of an instance are left non-`const`

Answer (score 8):

In this case you are calling a non-const method on a const reference which isn't allowed. You have two options:

1. Do what you did and `const_cast`
2. Make `ContainsPoint` a const method

Comment: No, not (1).  Definitely (2).  Or make a local (non-const) copy of `line`, and call on the copy.  But don't ever use `const_cast` to remove `const` from an object unless you added it.  Ever.

Comment: I'll have to do what I did. Making ContainsPoint a const method will cause a chain reaction in the code of const-ing every subsequent method. Is the error generated because the making Line a const is a promise not to change it, and when I attempt to call a non-const method the compiler can't KNOW that the called method changes it, so it flags an error?

Comment: @Ben: Agreed. I've seen many people use `const_cast` in many inappropriate ways. Just to make a note, if you have a method which is conceptually constant, but still needs to change some private state, consider using the `mutable` keyword. I find it a great feature, especially when adding something like memoization to methods which are otherwise constant.

Comment: I would strongly consider making ContainsPoint const, it seems like it should be. And if I remember right, a const method can accept non-const reference but the converse is not true.

Comment: @Casey: That's pretty much it. The compiler won't deduce that a method is `const`, you have to tell it so. @Andrew: Even a non-const method can accept const references. The `const` keyword after the function head only adds `const`-ness to the current instance and to its members/

Comment: @Andrew: Sorry, I think I misinterpreted what you said. You are correct that calling a const method on a non-const instance works, while the opposite does not.

Comment: Const correctness improves the safety of your code. I would get the const correctness right now because it's only going snowball and get harder as your project grows. http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html

Comment: @Casey - sometimes the chain reaction can't be avoided. It's the result of making bad choices early in the process.

Comment: Also, the earlier you experience situation involving a chain reaction, the earlier you will learn to consider const-correctedness (and other design issues) as a forethought, not an afterthought (at least, I hope so!!)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in fact a simple one:

you have a class A, with a **non-const** method foo(), you are invoking non-const method foo() through a ref to const A.

```
const A& a = ...;
a.foo();  // failed
```

That's what const aimed for: a const variable means, it is declared not going to be changed.  While foo() "is going to change itself" (as foo() is a non-const method, which means: "I am legal to change thing inside"), that's why compiler complains: you have a const var (a), but you are going to change its content (thru foo())

The way to solve is straight forward, but you should know which way is correct to do:

1) If you are sure that foo() should be legal to be invoked through const ref etc, you should declare it as a const method:   A::foo() const {...}

2) If you know that foo() is not appropriate to make const, you should consider

2.1) review "a" to see if it is more appropriate to make non-const, or

2.2) find another const method in A that did the work.

(There are some other way like using mutable, or const_cast, but that's not the way to go for 99.9% of time. So I didn't mention here)