# How to create copy constructor in C++/CX with class having properties

Tags: c++, windows-runtime, c++-cx

I'm new to C++/CX. I want to create a Vector class with two properties X and Y.

In standard C++, the copy constructor is:

```
Vector(const Vector& v);
```

I translate that to C++/CX as:

```
Vector(const Vector^ v);
```

Here's the class:

Header:

```
ref class Vector
{
public:
    Vector();
    Vector(const Vector^ v);

    property double X;
    property double Y;
};
```

Implementation:

```
Vector::Vector()
{
    X = 0;
    Y = 0;
}

Vector::Vector(const Vector^ v)
{
    this->X = v->X;
    this->Y = v->Y;
}
```

But I got an error when assigning v->X to this->X as: no instance of function "Vector::X::get" matches the argument list and object (the object as type qualifiers that prevent a match).

How to implement the copy constructor correctly?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you even need a copy constructor? `ref class` is always used by a reference, so you will always copy just the reference, no need for a copy constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is not directly related to copy-constructors. When I compile your code, I get the following error:

> 'Vector::X::get' : cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const Vector' to 'Vector %'

This shows that the problem is with `const`-ness, see for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6619360/41071) and its accepted answer.

It seems like the problem is that for trivial properties, the `get` accessor is not declared `const`. Because of that, you can't access the property on a `const Vector^`.

I think a solution would be not to use trivial properties, but implement both accessors yourself, making the `get` accessor `const`:

```
private:
    double x;
    double y;
public:
    property double X
    {
        double get() const { return x; }
        void set(double value) { x = value; }
    }

    property double Y
    {
        double get() const { return y; }
        void set(double value) { y = value; }
    }
```

The problem with this approach is that you can't have `const` methods in WinRT types (which, I assume, is why `get` accessors are not `const` in trivial properties). So, if you changed your type to `public ref class`, you would get this error:

> 'get': 'const' and 'volatile' qualifiers on member functions of WinRT types are not supported

Because of that, I think your best option is to not use `const` in your copy constructor:

```
Vector::Vector(Vector^ v)
{
    this->X = v->X;
    this->Y = v->Y;
}
```

Although I'm not sure why would you even need a copy constructor for `ref class`, since you always use it as a reference.

Comment: I'm porting some standard C++ to C++/CX. I forgot the fact that by using `ref class`, the object will never be passed by value.
Thanks for your answer. I'll omit the copy constructor.

Comment: If you desire value semantics on a class, there are some scenarios where a 'value class' may be appropriate instead.  Note that value classes are very constrained; they can only contain strings, fundamental types, and other value classes.